# vue router in Apache server cause problem

Tags: vue.js, apache, vuejs3, vue-router4

my question is about vue3 and vuerouter@4
i recently deployed my small vue project in apache server, i configured .htaccess most router link working perfectly handled by apache https://example.com/note, https://example.com/login ... ,
but my issue is when i try to access https://example.com/note/any it work if i start browsing from the home but when i reload it or directly go to https://example.com/anything it always blank, i tried many apache htaccess still not work pleaase help. (in local perfectly working only in production have this issue , i think problem is related to apache .htaccess)
here is my router/index.js

```
{

            path: "/note/:anytext([A-Za-z0-9]{1,10})",
            name: "notes",
            component: Notes,
            
        },
```

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

dev tool console show this error , i hosted in Hestia cp

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

i have issue related to vue router apache server

edit: now i got solution thanks to phil

i was used this in vite config
base: './',

but base should be '/'

Comment: Any errors in the browser dev-tools console on those _blank_ pages?

Comment: Here is dev-tool console:::

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Are you using Vite to build your app? If so, see https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path

Comment: ok sir thanks, i check that vite guide.

Comment: here is  my vite.config.js file:::

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: './',
})

Comment: `./` is for embedded apps. Use `/` instead. See https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base. Why did you change it from the default?

Comment: thank you very much , now perfectly working.